Identifying and Fixing Memory Leaks with Python's gc Module
I have a complex Python application where I'm experiencing memory leaks over time. I'm using a lot of objects with circular references, but I've ensured that del methods are not causing issues. How can I use Python's gc module to identify and debug these memory leaks? What are the best practices for managing memory in Python to prevent leaks in long-running applications?
Implementing del: I ensured that my classes had del methods defined correctly, even though they are not causing the leaks.

This answer suggests using weakref instead of circular references.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is a similar question with many good answers. The top answer links to a nice tutorial on how to trace python memory leaks.
In most use cases, you should not care about the "del" methods. Instead, you should ensure that you remove all references to unneeded objects.
